# node js backend returning undefined value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

[image]im trying to send a error request back the the client and its not sending correctly in node js

its supposed to either report back as success or error.message so i can send to the client.

```
 class FirebaseHelper    
 {
//universal SUCCESS or ERROR message to send to client


//register user with email and password


register(email,password,username,fullname,db)
{ 

   //firebase auth create user

  const p = admin.auth().createUser({
    email: email,
    emailVerified: false,
    password: password,         
    })
    .then(() => {
      // on successs
      let docRef = db.collection('users').doc(email);

      let setAda = docRef.set({
        username: username,
        fullname: fullname,

      })
      var ResponseMessage = new String();
      ResponseMessage = '';
      console.log('Successfully created new user:', email)
      ResponseMessage = handleresponse('Success');
      return ResponseMessage;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      //on failure
      var ResponseMessage = new String();
      ResponseMessage = '';
      ResponseMessage = handleresponse(`${error.message}`);
      return ResponseMessage;

    }); 
   return p

};  

function handleresponse(R)
{

ResponseMessage = R;
console.log(`${ResponseMessage}`)
return ResponseMessage;
};
```

that is where i get response on success response or error response

here is main.js where i get the request and then send it back to client

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

 const FirebaseHelper = require('./FirebaseHelper')
 const FirebaseHelper1 = new FirebaseHelper();

[![console][1]][1]//create express service
 const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
module.exports = app;

  app.post('/register', (request, response) =>{
  console.log('request tried')
  success = new Boolean;
  REQUEST_DATA = request.body;

   if(REQUEST_DATA!== null){
    console.log(REQUEST_DATA);
    REQUEST_EMAIL = REQUEST_DATA.email;
    REQUEST_PASSWORD = REQUEST_DATA.password;
    REQUEST_USERNAME = REQUEST_DATA.username;
    REQUEST_FULLENAME = REQUEST_DATA.fullname;
    var RESPONSE = new String();

   RESPONSE = FirebaseHelper1.register(REQUEST_EMAIL,
REQUEST_PASSWORD,
REQUEST_USERNAME,
REQUEST_FULLENAME,db);

  if(RESPONSE === 'Success'){
    response.send({
      success: true,
      info: `sucess`
    });
  }
  else{
    response.send({
      success: false,
      info: `${RESPONSE}`
    });
  };


}
else{
console.log('request was null');

};

})
```

this is how i display it to the user

```
 async private void registerUser_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterUser response;
        string JSONresponse = await 
  apiRequestHelper.RequestRegisterUserAsync((RinputEmail.Text).ToString(), 
  (RinputPassword.Text).ToString(), (RinputUsername.Text).ToString(), 
(RinputFullName.Text).ToString());
         response = jsonHelper.deserializeRegisterResponse(JSONresponse);
        if (response.success == true) {
            await DisplayAlert("Alert", response.info, "OK");
            await Navigation.PushAsync(new Login());
        };
        if (response.success == false)
        {

            await DisplayAlert("Alert", response.info, "OK");
        }
        else {

            await DisplayAlert("Alert", "idk man", "OK");

        };
    }
```

register user class

```
namespace Kula.Models
{
public class RegisterUser
{
  public bool success { get; set; }
  public string info { get; set; }
}
}
```

the boolean comes back true or false but the string is always undefined plz help been stuck for hours.

how it looks to user

[image: updated photo]

Comment: Are you sure `${error.message}` is defined in catch block? What if you console.log it?

Comment: @ShivamSood in handleresponse() at the bottom i do console.log it and it does show up for some reason the image of the console i added didnt show up ill add it again.

Comment: @ShivamSood i added the pic its on the top of the post

Comment: In your `main.js` can you explain what's the use of this `RESPONSE =  FirebaseHelper1.ResponseMessage;` I never used Firebase so kind of confused

Comment: @ShivamSood oops i i forgot that was like that i updated my code and the picture. it should make more sense now. the response to the client is different but still not the error.message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well Actually the Updated picture clears up the situation and I believe what is happening that you are returning `promise` instead of the actual `value`.
In your `register` function remove `return p` and it should work.

Comment: but then register returns void. and no value is assigned it. and it returns Promise<string> when i assign constant. how would i implement a way to return a string contains the error.message. i cant seem to get the scope right.

Comment: because i can get the error.message and log it into the console but no matter what i do i cant seem to get it to return that value.